# Javascript add array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

First of all I am new to JavaScript.

I would like to insert variables into this type of array dynamically that containing latitude and longitude. Hoping for helps...

```
var locations = [
  [ test, test1],
  [ -33.923036, 151.259052],
  [ -34.028249, 151.157507],
  [ -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
];
```

var test = -33.923036;
  var test1 = 151.259052;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue ? What is `console.log(locations)` ?

Comment: locations.push(test);

Comment: I tried with array splice but i didnt get to know how to add array into another array?

Comment: `locations.push([test, test1])`. Or with `.splice()` (since you tried to use that, though `.push()` is a much better option): `locations.splice(someIndex, 0, [test, test1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

You have to use push method to insert an object to array.

```js
var test = -33.923036; var test1 = 151.259052;

var locations = [
 
  [ -33.923036, 151.259052],
  [ -34.028249, 151.157507],
  [ -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
]; 

locations.push([test, test1])

console.log(locations)
```

Comment: *You have to use push method to insert* - You don't *have to* use that method: `.push()` is just one of several ways to add an element to an array, and note that it doesn't "insert" so much as "append".

Comment: Yes Indeed. there are always many options. Its just what came to my mind when I read the question :) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use push method to add new element in an array.

```
var newValues = [test,test1];
locations.push(newValues);
```

Comment: can we add both test and test1 together? using push

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this `locations.push([variable_name_1,variable_name_2])`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `test` and `test1` before `locations`:

```js
var test = 1, test1 = 2;

var locations = [
  [ test, test1],
  [ -33.923036, 151.259052],
  [ -34.028249, 151.157507],
  [ -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
]; 

console.log(locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = -33.923036; var test1 = 151.259052;
var locations = [
 [ test, test1],
 [ -33.923036, 151.259052],
 [ -34.028249, 151.157507],
 [ -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
 [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
];
```

or

```
var locations = [
 [ -33.923036, 151.259052],
 [ -34.028249, 151.157507],
 [ -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
 [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
]; 

locations.push([-33.923036,151.259052])
```

or

```
var test = -33.923036; var test1 = 151.259052;

locations.push([test,test1])
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: `[ \`${test}\`, \`${test1}\`]` makes no sense: why would you convert the values to strings when all of the other array items are numbers?

Answer (score 0):

First declare your variable

```
var test = -33.923036; var test1 = 151.259052;
```

then perform push

```
locations.push([test,test1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic insert of some values, you could wrap it in the array, you need and access as before.

If you change the value inside of `loc`, you get the actual value in `loations` as well, because you have a reference between  `loc` and `locations[0]`.

As long as you do not overwrite `locations[0]`, with a new array or primitive value, you could access the actual value of `loc`.

```js
var loc = [
        -33.923036,
        151.259052
    ],
    locations = [
        loc,
        [-33.923036, 151.259052],
        [-34.028249, 151.157507],
        [-33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
        [-33.950198, 151.259302 ]
    ]; 

console.log(locations[0][0]); // -33.923036
loc[0] = 42;
console.log(locations[0][0]); // 42
locations[0][0] = -10;
console.log(locations[0][0]); // -10
console.log(loc);             // [-10,  151.259052]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.